# XML/DTD, proper valid declaration of a href element?

Tags: xml, dtd

Alright so I'm working with DTD in a class and based off of two validators, this specific problem exists in where:

```
21: 63  Element type "a" must be declared.
```

this is the line(s) in XML that pertain to this error.

```
<etymology><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Adams">John Adams</a> (1735-1826), 2nd <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_United_States">U.S. President</a></etymology>
```

this is my DTD Declaration:

```
<!ELEMENT etymology (#PCDATA)>
```

Since the 'a href' are not entirely required or not even always there to begin with with each passing  etymology element in the XML file, how would I properly declare them?

I also have the same situation at the bottom of the XML files where a footnote element has hrefs in it and I wonder the same for them.

```
<footnote id="g">Quillehuyte County was split from Jefferson and Clallam counties in 1868 and returned to those counties a year later.</footnote>
```

__

```
<!ELEMENT footnote (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST footnote id CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: Is the <a href> from HTML? If you want to allow <etymology> and <footnote> to contain arbitrary HTML, you might want to make them CDATA.

Comment: Yes this is pretty much HTML links within the Etymology and Footnote elements, I have tried doing <!ELEMENT a (#PCDATA)> and <!ATTLIST a href CDATA #IMPLIED> and it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to declare [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content) (contains both elements and #PCDATA). Basically the order and occurrences of the child elements can't be constrained.

Quote from link above:

> ...the types of the child elements may be constrained, but not their
>   order or their number of occurrences

Here's how you would modify your `etymology` declaration:

```
<!ELEMENT etymology (#PCDATA|a)*>
```

You would do the same with `footnote`:

```
<!ELEMENT footnote (#PCDATA|a)*>
```